# Javascript regex for words including spaces and other characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

String search : 'authorizations'

*Actual :*

**Authorizations**

PCP / **Authorizations**

*Expected is :*

**Authorizations**

PCP / Authorizations

I am trying to bold the search results, but I want to bold only the exact matches. I used this regex but it does not gives the desired result.

```
        $(event.target).autocomplete({
                        minLength: 1,
                        source: $(event.target).attr("data-source").replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            var term = this.term,
                regex = new RegExp('\\b' + term + '\\b', 'gi');
                label = item.label.replace(regex, '<b style="font-weight: bold;">$&</b>');
                $link = $("<a></a>").html(label);
            return $("<li></li>").append($link).appendTo(ul);
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to bold on exact equivalence, then why not just use `==` to compare the string:

```
    $(event.target).autocomplete({
                    minLength: 1,
                    source: $(event.target).attr("data-source").replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        var term = this.term;
        if (item.label == 'Authorizations') {
            label = '<b style="font-weight: bold;">Authorizations</b>';
        }
        else {
            label = item.label;
        }
        $link = $("<a></a>").html(label);

        return $("<li></li>").append($link).appendTo(ul);
    };
```

Comment: But this does not bolds the word.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Try <b style="font-weight: 'bold';">Authorizations</b>

Comment: Sorry my bad, the item.label was having a white space before it. Thus it was not working.